# Spring x.509 authentication only for certain port

Tags: spring-security, x509

I would like to have the following scenario in my Spring app:

- All connections to port 8440 have one-side https authentication (only the server is authenticated)
- All connections to port 8441 have two-size http authentication (so the client must provide a valid X.509 cert)

How can I configure my `spring-security.xml` file to achieve this? Ideally, I'd like to be able to express something like this:

```
<http port=8441 use-expressions="true">
  <http-basic entry-point-ref="ambariEntryPoint" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" method="GET"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" method="DELETE"/>
  <x509 subject-principal-regex="(.*)" />
</http>
<http port=8440 use-expressions="true">
  <http-basic entry-point-ref="ambariEntryPoint" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />
</http>
```

Is the are way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It was helpful. I have marked it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not do it with Spring Security. The client authentication is performed by Servlet container (or the WebServer behind it).
You can configure two different web applications. Then you need to configure Servlet container for Client Certificate authentication for the first application and only SSL for the second application.
Spring Security will allow to take Client Certificate information using `<x509>` filter